# get values from lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, splistitem, android

I have a list named Users which contains two fields namely User(user or person) and Region(Lookup),In which Region points to another field('Name') of another list named Region which contains fields namely Name,Latitude,Longitude,Radius.Below is a query which I wrote to filter out Latitude,Longitude,Radius of the current User.

```
http://cloudapps.cctspl.com/sites/ClockInClockOut/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Users')/items?$select=User/Name,Region/Name,Region/Latitude,Region/Longitude,Region/Radius&$expand=User,Region&$filter=User/Name eq 'gopal@cctspl.com'
```

But when I use the above link its returning me an Id but i'm not getting the values(Lat,Lng,Radius) of the corresponding user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per given query by you in $filter section, you are using Email address for "User/Name" field.. Try this REST url

> http://cloudapps.cctspl.com/sites/ClockInClockOut/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Users')/items?$select=User/Name,Region/Name,Region/Latitude,Region/Longitude,Region/Radius&$expand=User,Region&$filter=User/EMail eq 'gopal@cctspl.com'

Comment: Welcome bro.. Please up vote answer..